Entity Framework - how can I have a valueObject with a relation one to many with an entity in DB context?
I have an entity called horario that has a list of horarioDiario. horarioDiario is a valueObject.
One horario could have many (7) horarioDiario and one horarioDiario could have one horario.
(horario is like a time slot that has many horarioDiario and horarioDiario is a dayOfWeek)
because horarioDiarios is a valueObject doesnt have an Id, so my primary key is horarioId from the entity and DiaSemana (horarioDiario parameter).
This code below doesnt work. I needed to edit the migration to have this tables
DB tables
builder.OwnsMany(horario => horario.HorariosDiarios, horariosDiarios => { var horarioId = horariosDiarios.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("HorarioId");
 horariosDiarios.HasKey(hd => new {horarioId, hd.DiaSemana }); 
// In this line the horarioId is wrong (the error): 


Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The expression 'hd => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(horarioId = value(Planning.Infrastructure.Data.Configurations.HorarioConfiguration+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).horarioId, DiaSemana = hd.DiaSemana)' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.DiaSemana).IsRequired();
        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.HoraInicio).IsRequired();
        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.HoraFim).IsRequired();
    });

My question is what I need to change in order to have the png image behavior without change the migrations? (Changing the builder ownsMany code)
builder.OwnsMany(horario => horario.HorariosDiarios, horariosDiarios => { var horarioId = horariosDiarios.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("HorarioId");      

  horariosDiarios.HasKey(hd => new {horarioId, hd.DiaSemana }); 

        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.DiaSemana).IsRequired();
        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.HoraInicio).IsRequired();
        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.HoraFim).IsRequired();
    });

public class Horario { public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }

public virtual DateOnly DataInicio { get; private set; }
public virtual DateOnly DataFim { get; private set; }

private List<HorarioDiario> _horariosDiarios;

public IReadOnlyList<HorarioDiario> HorariosDiarios => _horariosDiarios.AsReadOnly();

private Horario(DateOnly dataInicio, DateOnly dataFim)
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    DataInicio = dataInicio;
    DataFim = dataFim;
    _horariosDiarios = [];
}

public record HorarioDiario { public DayOfWeek DiaSemana { get; } public TimeOnly HoraInicio { get; } public TimeOnly HoraFim { get; }

private HorarioDiario(DayOfWeek diaSemana, TimeOnly horaInicio, TimeOnly horaFim)
{
    DiaSemana = diaSemana;
    HoraInicio = horaInicio;
    HoraFim = horaFim;
}

public class HorarioConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Horario> 
{ public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Horario> builder) {
builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);      

  //Propriedade Id
        builder.Property(a => a.Id)
               .IsRequired()
               .ValueGeneratedNever();

        // Propriedade HorarioDiario
        builder.OwnsMany(horario => horario.HorariosDiarios, horariosDiarios =>
    {
        var horarioId = horariosDiarios.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("HorarioId");

        horariosDiarios.HasKey(hd => new { horarioId, hd.DiaSemana });

        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.DiaSemana).IsRequired();
        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.HoraInicio).IsRequired();
        horariosDiarios.Property(a => a.HoraFim).IsRequired();
    });
    }
}

